# Using openpyxl to write to a cell in a '.xlsm' excel, can't open in windows xp?

Tags: python, windows, excel, openpyxl, vba

I am using openpyxl to write data in a cell, but it can't be opened in Windows xp, while it can be opened in Windows7. In office 2007.

```
wb = load_workbook('book2.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws['A1'] = u'hello1234'
wb.save('book2.xlsm')
```

There are VBA buttons in 'book2.xlsm'. Can't open 'book2.xlsm' in Windows xp after saving. But if I change something(even add a space) in 'book2.xlsm' and save it, it can be opened in Windows xp. Why?
And if there some better way to write to a cell in '.xlsm' excel?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the precise problem is but openpyxl no longer supports Office 2007 but the OOXML specification that was ratified **after** Office 2007 was shipped. This means that there are some subtle changes and some things that Office 2007 doesn't support.

You might be able to use the OOXML Productivity Tool to compare the two files and then submit a bug report but **no** changes specifically for Office 2007 will be made.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is why I can't open the 'book2.xlsm' in windows xp which can be opened in win7. 'book2.xlsm' was written by openpyxl.

Comment: That's a question only Microsoft can answer. My best guess is that you have different versions of Office installed.